# how to inherit a protected/private of an abstract class in Scala

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, functional-programming, abstract-class

I've got an abstract class with an object and a concrete subclass representing a binary tree for sorting a group of strings lexicographically.

```
abstract class StringSet {
  def incl(x:String):StringSet
  def contains(x:String):Boolean
  def union(that:StringSet):StringSet

  def biggest:String // this is my new method
  def bigIter(acc:String):String //this is my new helper method
}
object Empty extends StringSet {
  override def toString: String = "."
  def incl(x: String): StringSet = new NonEmpty(x, Empty, Empty)
  def contains(x: String): Boolean = false
  def union(that:StringSet):StringSet = that

  def biggest:String = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("...")
  def bigIter(acc:String):String = acc
}
class NonEmpty(elem:String, left:StringSet, right:StringSet) extends StringSet {
  def incl(x: String): StringSet = {
    if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this
  }
  def contains(x: String): Boolean = {
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true
  }
  def union(that:StringSet):StringSet = ((left union right) union that) incl elem

  def biggest:String =  bigIter(elem)
  def bigIter(acc:String):String = 
    if (elem < acc) left union right bigIter acc
    else left union right bigIter elem
}
```

I want to implement a method for obtaining the biggest string, using only the already created methods for that class in a "functional way". I used the method "biggest" with no parameters that return a string, that calls another method "bigIter" who recursively call itself until it traverses all the tree.

My idea worked, but I want to hide the bigIter implementation, in order for a user could only see the method "Biggest". I used protected and private for bigIter on the abstract and concrete classes, but it didn't work. I tried using private with bigIter method in the abstract class, but private methods of a superclass cannot be inherited. I tried with protected too, using it with both the superclass and the subclasses, getting the following error

> Error:(50, 39) method bigiter in class StringSet cannot be accessed in
>   A$A3.this.StringSet  Access to protected method bigiter not permitted
>   because  prefix type A$A3.this.StringSet does not conform to  class
>   NonEmpty in class A$A3 where the access take place
>       if (elem < acc) left union right bigiter acc
>                                        ^

Any ideas of how could this be accomplished?

note: 
1. calling biggest on Empty should return an error, so that's why I call "bigIter" from the concrete classes.
2. This is for a course I'm doing, so the idea is not to use higher order list functions.

Comment: *"I used protected and private for bigIter on the abstract and concrete classes, but it didn't work."* What didn't work? What was the error?

Comment: If I understand your definition of "biggest" correctly, shouldn't you only need to look to the `right` subset?

Comment: `private` things are not inherited. What didn't work about `protected`?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov  I updated the question with your observations. thank you

Comment: @Jasper-M I used `protected` too. I updated the question with the output I got. Thank you

Comment: @JackLeow you are right! I'll take your suggestion, ty

Answer (score 3):

[SI-9890](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9890) explains why the compiler isn't happy when you try to access a method on a super type in a derived type instance. [The specification restricts this:](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#protected)

> A protected identifier `x` may be used as a member name in a selection
> `r.x` only if one of the following applies:
>
> - The access is within the template defining the member, or, if a qualification `C` is given, inside the package `C`, or the class `C`, or its companion module, or
> - `r` is one of the reserved words this and super, or
> - **`r's` type conforms to a type-instance of the class which contains the access.**

The last bullet basically means `r`, which in your case is `StringSet`, must be of type `NonEmpty`.

To get around this, you can place all your implementations of `StringSet` under the same package and have a `protected[package]` set on `bigIter`. For example, assume your package name is `foo`, you can do:

```
protected[foo] def bigIter(acc: String): String
```

And now it will compile.